# XML Validation in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring

Good Evening,

I am trying to setup a simple spring tutorial in eclipse and after following it I seem to have an issue in my two .xml files.

the error in eclipse says that the element type "beans" must be followed with > or /> which i understand ... but just looking at this it seems that it is being closed. Im not sure what is wrong with either file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

> <property **name="viewClass"v alue**="org.springframework

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong. Right click in your file and do Validate again after you fix that.

Comment: I accidently did that in an edit, eriginal question did not have the "v alue

Comment: Like takteek said, there's nothing wrong with your xml, sometimes eclipse just needs a restart.

Comment: Have you considered not having line breaks in your attribute values? How's the syntax colored?

Comment: The syntax appears to be colored as i would expect. The error pops up on the first line <beans xmlns ....  But I can tell you that the project loads and the index page loads on the server ... but the test link does not link back through spring the way it should. I get a 404 error that http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTutorial/hello.html is not available.